# IE10 not enforcing CSS cursor rules when element is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

Using the CSS:

```
* {cursor:none;}
body {cursor:none; }
```

IE10 successfully hides the cursor in the document, until I use JavaScript or jQuery to change an element's style to (display:none;} on a click event.

When an element is clicked and hidden, the cursor reappears where the element used to be, despite the `cursor:none` rule. Clicking anywhere else on the document once again hides the cursor.

Content is held in a container div, and when buttons are used to progress through the site (using ajax), the holder and the action buttons contained inside it are hidden (using position, which is fastest in this instance) and emptied:

```
elements.container.style.top = -768;
elements.container.innerHTML = '';
$(".loading-progress").show();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hiding the cursor is an extremely bad idea anyway...

Comment: It's necessary in this instance.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that. You should be much better off looking into Pointer Lock, but I can't say for certain without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: If it's true, it's some kind of bug where they are only affecting the Nodes that are that are on top of other Nodes. Show code please.

Comment: There is no Pointer Lock support for IE10 as far as I can tell, and your sincere doubts are irrelevant to the question, as I can assure you, in this instance, the mouse must be hidden.

Comment: What is `elements.container`? And why are you mixing jQuery with JavaScript. If using jQuery, use it. Still need more code.

Comment: @PHPglue elements.container is just a div that ajax data is loaded into and out of. I am mixing jQuery with JavaScript because JavaScript is faster for certain functions.

Comment: can you put a little more code together ....maybe something in jsfiddle?